# Парсинг сайта с помощью JSOUP

Tags: android, парсер, jsoup

С помощью JSOUP хочу получить из тега `"id_default_image"` с атрибутом `xlink:href` 
  значение http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/images/products/1/1. Как это сделать?

```
<product>      
 <id_default_image xlink:href="http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/images/products/1/1"                                                           notFilterable="true">
    <![CDATA[ 1 ]]>
    </id_default_image>
    <reference>
    <![CDATA[ demo_1 ]]>
    </reference>
```

мой код выводит значения из

```
elements = document.select("id_default_image");

for(Element link : elements){

       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, link ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Comment: `link.attr("xlink:href")`

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён

```
String elem = document.select("id_default_image").get(0).attr("xlink:href");
```